# Moga Power Pro, HID mode, in Chrome 46 for Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, aurelia, gamepad

I've written a small Aurelia application that binds to gamepad state here:

http://davismj.github.io/challenger/

I developed it using my Moga Power Pro in HID mode connected to my Windows 7 computer. However, it failed to detect the same gamepad when I opened it in Chrome 46 on my Nexus 5 (Marshmallow). I can confirm that the [gamepad tester](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/doodles/gamepad/gamepad-tester/tester.html) app also fails to detect the gamepad.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? Can I report and track the issue somewhere?

I'm particularly surprised because the gamepad is **not** supported on windows, but well supported on Android on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gamepad was detected, but you need to press a button first.